# How to "name" each JSON object

Tags: r, json, object, jsonlite

I am sure this is a rather simple thing to do, but I am not able to figure it out.

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
a   b   c
1   9   J
2   5   K
```

When I use toJSON and pass the dataframe as a named list

```
val <- toJSON(list( table = df), pretty = TRUE)
```

I get:

```
{  "table":[
   {
     {
       "a":"1",
       "b":"9",
       "c":"J"
     }
   },
   {
     {
       "a":"2",
       "b":"5",
       "c":"K"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

How can I get each JSON object to be named "entry" as shown below:

```
{  "table":[
   {
     "entry":{
       "a":"1",
       "b":"9",
       "c":"J"
     }
   },
   {
     "entry":{
       "a":"2",
       "b":"5",
       "c":"K"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Try `toJSON(list( table = list(entry = df)), pretty = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, but that only adds entry to the first object.  '''{  "table":[
   {
     "entry":{
       "a":"1",
       "b":"9",
       "c":"J",
     }
   },
   {
     {
       "a":"2",
       "b":"5",
       "c":"K",
     }
   }
   }
 ]
}

Comment: @akrun is close but not quite right; each row of the data.frame needs to be converted to a named list

Answer (score 1):

To get the structure you want is a bit complicated becaues of the `{"entry":{"a":1,"b":9,"c":"J"}}` object

To get this structure you need to have a named list

```
lst <- list( list(a = 1, b = 9, c = "J") )
attr( lst, "names" ) <- "entry"

toJSON( lst, auto_unbox = TRUE )
# {"entry":{"a":1,"b":9,"c":"J"}}
```

Therefore each row of your data.frame needs to be a named list

```
res <- lapply( seq_len( nrow( df ) ), function(i) {
  lst <- list( as.list( df[i, , drop = F] ) )
  attr( lst, "names" ) <- "entry"
  lst
})

## add the 'table'
res <- list( table = res )

toJSON( res, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE )
# {
#   "table": [
#     {
#       "entry": {
#         "a": 1,
#         "b": 9,
#         "c": "J"
#       }
#     },
#     {
#       "entry": {
#         "a": 2,
#         "b": 5,
#         "c": "K"
#       }
#     }
#   ]
# }
```